# Visualize Geohash after Drawing it on same map (Streamlit Folium)

Tags: python, streamlit, folium, geohashing

need some helps here, I’m still a rookie in this streamlit stuffs so feel free to give some feedback upon my codes. Here is the problems, I create tools using streamlit and Draw plugin, whenever user draw polygon on certain areas, it will create geohash visualizations. I have difficulty to overlay the geohash above drawing layer. Here is my code

```
import folium
import geopandas as gpd
import json
import numpy as np
import streamlit as st
from polygeohasher import polygeohasher
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely import wkt
from streamlit_folium import st_folium
from folium.plugins import Draw
from streamlit_folium import st_folium


button = st.number_input('Insert a Geohash number')
number = int(button)

c1, c2 = st.columns(2)
with c1:
    m = folium.Map([-6.175300560878783, 106.82701205991948],zoom_start=16)
    Draw(export=False).add_to(m)

    output = st_folium(m, width=1200, height=800)

    geojson_str = json.dumps(output)
    geojson_data = gpd.read_file(geojson_str, driver='GeoJSON')
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(geojson_data)


    geohash_gdf = polygeohasher.create_geohash_list(gdf, number,inner=False)
    geohash_gdf_list = polygeohasher.geohashes_to_geometry(geohash_gdf,"geohash_list")
    gpd_geohash_geom = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geohash_gdf_list, geometry=geohash_gdf_list['geometry'], crs="EPSG:4326")
    geojson_geohash = gpd_geohash_geom.to_json()
    folium.features.GeoJson(geojson_geohash,
                            tooltip = folium.GeoJsonTooltip(fields = ['geohash_list']),
                            style_function = lambda x:{
                                          'color': 'blue'                                      
                                     }).add_to(m)
with c2:
    st_folium(m, width=1200, height=800)

csv=gpd_geohash_geom.to_csv()
st.download_button(
    label="Download data as CSV",
    data=csv,
    file_name='geohash_file.csv',
    mime='text/csv',
)
```

Please Help, Thanks